# Configure Application Gateway with API Management using Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azureportal, azure-application-gateway

The azure docs describing the integration of API Management with Application Gateway in a VNet (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway) consists of quite complex steps that are not so intuitive.

Is there any intuitive way most probably via Azure portal to integrate the above 2 components ? The same issue is also posted on feedback docs. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/39301564-documentation-fully-featured-application-gateway

I set up the application gateway as follows with the settings:
Listener settings:
[image]

Backend pool settings:
[image]

The IP Address is the private IP of the API Management in the same Vnet as the Application gateway

HTTP Settings:
[image]

1. On the API management site I have configured an API to send a mock response and its configured as a normal GET request to path "/". Do I need to configure anything else on the API management side also ?
2. I am doing this for testing purposes so I kept the protocol as HTTP. Do I still need certificates to configure the custom domain names or will the private IP of API management work ?

Upon doing a GET request on the front end IP of gateway it is giving me 5** error.

Help please.

Comment: I agree. I'm not fan of Application Gateway  because of that too. Have you tried replacing Application Gateway by Azure Front Door?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio no I need to use Application Gateway only.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to enable SNI in the listener of Application Gateway via Portal. Other steps are configurable via Portal.

Let me know if you face any issue while creation of AppGW via portal.

Comment: Can you please look at the configuration above ? I edited the query for better clarity.

Comment: 502 error can be probe failure. Check your backend health. Also if you are using SSL offloading, then you don't need certificate. Create a custom probe as per the doc and associate it to the HTTP Settings.

Comment: 502 was the deafult probe failure. I configured a VM on the same VNet for DNS resolving as provided in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-internal-vnet#apim-dns-configuration) After this I am not able to understand where and how should I configure this VM in gateway so that traffic goes from gateway and the IP address is resolved to my API management hostname.